# Drill Down Chart find Index returns -1

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

Hi I am trying to get a Drill Down Chart working in my Angular APP. I try it with `findIndex` but it returns me `-1` every time but I don't get any Error messages on my Console. Can some one help me with this problem ?
I just want to get the Index of the clicked pie part only.

this is my function:

```js
chartLabels: string[] = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"];
chartData: number[] = [30, 10, 5, 15, 40, 7, 3, 20];


drillDownClick(myData){
    const chartLabels: string[] = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"];
  
    const x = myData.findIndex(i => i.chartData >= 0);
    alert(x);
};
```

EDIT for better understanding this is my `onClick`:

```js
public drillChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    onClick: () => this.drillDownClick(this.chartData),
```

Comment: what is the type of `myData` ? within findIndex `i` will be an element of it if its an array. try debugging if it really is the type you expect.

Comment: `myData` is of type `any`.

Comment: please provide some context how `drillDownClick` is called. `any` is just the type Typescript gives you if it cant find any better and you dont specify what it is exactly (which you should by the way) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any

Comment: i provided the information in the **EDIT** section

Comment: in this case the type of myData is the type of `chartData`, which is `number[]`.
findIndex will iterate on `number`s which has no .chartData property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the type of `myData` is the type of chartData, which is `number[]`. findIndex will iterate on numbers which has no .chartData property.

```
const x = myData.findIndex(i => i >= 0);
```

Comment: what do you want to achive? since all the chartData items are larger than zero, findIndex will give you the first item. the first item's index is 0.

Answer (score 0):

"chartData" is not a property of i.
"i" within the findIndex callback is an entry of "myData".
So "i.chartData" is wrong.

I don't know the actual context but try to replace "i.chartData" with "i" only.